# alert when a var equal div value

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to to show an alert message when my javascript `var` equal `div` value , here is what i am trying here :

```
function checkmydiv() {
    var ElementCssClass = document.getElementById("Target");
    if (ElementCssClass == "hello")
    {
        alert("the div has a value");
    }
​}​
```

here is my html code

```
<div id="Target" >hello</div>

<input type="button" value="bader" onclick = "checkmydiv();" />​
```

i do not know where did i go wrong , nothing popup when i click the button `bader`

appreciated all the help :)

Comment: you are checking if the element equals "hello". You need to compare with the content of the element instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get the text content from that element. Right now, you're comparing the object reference against `hello`which obviously won't work.

```
if (ElementCssClass.textContent == "hello") {
}
```

is what you're looking for.

One word auf caution: `.textContent` is supported by all modern browsers (=latest versions). However, old'ish version of IE might not recognize that property. So you might want to either do something like

```
var myText = ElementCssClass.textContent || ElementCssClass.text;
```

and then compare the value from `myText` against `hello` or just use `ElementCssClass.innerHTML`. I'd prefer the former solution because using `.innerHTML` might bring you in trouble in another sitations.

Comment: @BaderHAlRayyes: you had the wrong setup in that fiddle. Javascript needs to be in the head. Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/wpJKj/29/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the variable `ElementCssClass` is now a DOM node/object, not a string; you need to use `innerHTML` or, if supported, `innerText` or `textContent`:

```
function checkmydiv() {
    var ElementCssClass = document.getElementById("Target").innerHTML;

    if (ElementCssClass == "hello") {
        alert("the div has a value");
    }
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wpJKj/31/).

Also, just for good practice, might I recommend moving away from in-line JavaScript:

```
function checkmydiv() {
    var ElementCssClass = document.getElementById("Target");

    if (ElementCssClass.innerHTML == "hello") {
        alert("the div has value");
    }
}

var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0, len = input.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (input[i].value == 'bader') {
        input[i].onclick = function() {
            checkmydiv();
        }
    }
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wpJKj/33/).

And to reduce the need to hard-code the elements/text-content for comparison, you can pass arguments into the function:

```
function checkmydiv(id, str) {
    var ElementCssClass = document.getElementById(id);

    if (ElementCssClass.innerHTML == str) {
        alert("the div has value");
    }
    else {
        alert("the div does not have the value.");
    }
}

var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0, len = input.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (input[i].value == 'bader') {
        input[i].onclick = function() {
            checkmydiv('Target', 'hello');
        }
    }
    else if (input[i].value == 'bilder') {
        input[i].onclick = function() {
            checkmydiv('Target', 'some other string');
        }
    }
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wpJKj/35/).

References:

- [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.innerHTML).
- [`innerText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533899%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
- [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.textContent).

Comment: You're absolutely welcome, I'm glad to have been of any/some help! =)